# Finding the lowest value from list

Tags: group-by, min

I have a table "songs" which is like this

| Artist | Title | Pos | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| artist1 | title1 | 1 | 01-jan-1980 |
| artist2 | title0 | 9 | 01-jan-1980 |
| artist3 | title2 | 3 | 01-jan-1980 |
| artist1 | title1 | 1 | 07-jan-1980 |
| artist2 | title0 | 5 | 07-jan-1980 |
| artist3 | title2 | 4 | 07-jan-1980 |
| artist1 | title1 | 3 | 14-jan-1980 |
| artist2 | title0 | 6 | 14-jan-1980 |
| artist3 | title2 | 2 | 14-jan-1980 |

I'm trying group each Song (Title and Artist) by the lowest value of Pos so I would end up with

| Artist | Title | Pos | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| artist1 | title1 | 1 | 01-jan-1980 |
| artist2 | title0 | 5 | 07-jan-1980 |
| artist3 | title2 | 2 | 14-jan-1980 |

It would be efficient if the select statment that gets each song "GROUP by Artist, Title" could also get the lowest Pos value.

I attempted to have a separate select statement that would find each lowest Pos value for each song from within the while loop that finds each song.  E.g.

**First select statement**
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE Date > $yearstart AND Date < $yearend  Group BY Artist, Title ORDER BY Artist

**Then from within the while loop**
SELECT Position, Date FROM singles WHERE Artist = '".$row['Artist']."' AND Title = '".$row['Title']."' ORDER BY Date";

This works fine (for about 600 songs) as the first select statement is in some cases checking 10,000 rows and this second statement checks all 10,000 again for the lowest Pos value for each song.  Clearly that was going to be inefficient, and to the point MySQL aborted!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.Artist, s.Title, s.Pos, s.Date
from Songs s
inner join 
  ( SELECT artist, title, min(pos) as minPos 
    FROM songs 
    WHERE Date > $yearstart AND Date < $yearend 
    Group BY Artist, Title) m 
  on s.Artist = m.Artist and
     s.Title = m.Title and
     s.Pos = m.minPos
WHERE s.Date > $yearstart AND Date < $yearend
ORDER BY s.Artist
```